# Shortest possible way to determine the number of true cases in a statement

Tags: algorithm, powershell

I wrote a small series of if expressions in powershell, in which **0** to **n** cases could be true.

```
if (!(statement)) {increase errorcode by 1}
if (!(statement)) {increase errorcode by 2}
if (!(statement)) {increase errorcode by 4}
if (!(statement)) {increase errorcode by 8}
```

So I figured by adding the next multiple of two to the errorcode for every possibility, I get a unique sum for every possible combination of true cases.

Since I am not that mathematically enlightened: What is the easiest possible way to determine which cases are true, only based on the errorcode that is set after checking the if expressions?

Comment: convert the number to binary representation and see which positions are 1

Comment: Take binary representation of errorcode, 1 means condition was true, 0 false

Comment: for a specific position `x`, you can check if `errorCode & (1 << x)` is nonzero

Comment: Thanks, that sounds logical :) Is there a name for this kind of (mathematical) problem ?

Comment: I'd call this "bit arithmetics".

Comment: The expression `errorcode & 4 != 0` will tell you if errocode was increased by 4. (`!= 0` is probably optional but I don't know how powershell handles this)

Comment: Thanks Yves for this input. I will need to have a deeper look into these expressions.

Comment: Sounds like someone needs to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-band` to check if the bit is set to verify if a case was true. Ex:

```
$i = 0

$caseFlags = @{
    "Case1" = 1
    "Case2" = 2
    "Case3" = 4
    "Case4" = 8
}

if ($true) { $i += $caseFlags["Case1"] }
if ($true) { $i += $caseFlags["Case2"] }
if ($true) { $i += $caseFlags["Case3"] }
if ($false) { $i += $caseFlags["Case4"] }

"`$i is $i"

"Case1 true? $([bool]($i -band $caseFlags["Case1"]))"
"Case2 true? $([bool]($i -band $caseFlags["Case2"]))"
"Case3 true? $([bool]($i -band $caseFlags["Case3"]))"
"Case4 true? $([bool]($i -band $caseFlags["Case4"]))"
```

Output:

```
Case1 true? True
Case2 true? True
Case3 true? True
Case4 true? False
```

If you also need the count of true cases, you can use @mjolinor's answer.

Comment: This is actually what I needed. Thank you for this input!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to accept the chosen answer. Tip: Personally I would avoid the bitmask and just use a hashtable to store the values. Ex `$cases = @{}; $cases["case1"] = $true; $cases["case1"]`

Answer (score 0):

One option to count the number of true cases:

```
@([char[]][convert]::ToString($errorcode, 2) -eq '1').Count
```

The statement converts the binary representation of the number to a string (e.g. `5` → `"101"`), casts the string to a character array (`['1', '0', '1']`), and counts the characters that have the value `'1'` (`@(... -eq '1').Count`).

Comment: To me, this is very confusing. Could you post a short explanation of what this does? I see it with my own eyes but cant believe it works. But it does!

Comment: Executable line noise, anyone? ;)

Comment: I agree it's not particularly intuitive, but the request was for the "shortest possible way to determine the number of true cases". That's the shortest method I could come up with.

Comment: The title says number of true cases, but the question says which cases were true.

Comment: @FrodeF. $true enough, but the OP weighed in, and says it works, I assumed if it wan't the result he was looking for he'd have said so. At any rate, if somebody else has a better answer I'll withdraw this one.

Comment: You're right. I guess we kinda answered both sides of the question. Together we're strong... or something. :-)

Comment: Just to solve confusion ;) Frode F.'s answer nails it. Sorry for the misleading threadtitle. Though mjolinor seems to me like a pretty neat concept, that will be useful for me in the future too. Thanks for the answers.